# Exception logging in Pylons

Tags: python, exception, pylons, middleware

Is there a way to create a middleware that will catch every raised exception and print the stacktrace both to log and stdout (possibly with some additional information) in Pylons framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard [paste.exceptions.errormiddleware.ErrorMiddleware](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/exceptions.html#paste.exceptions.errormiddleware.ErrorMiddleware) already does this, and even a little more.